# adding to a nested xml element

Tags: c#, xml

I have the below code and wondering how to get "sold-product" element and add product to it.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
xmlDoc.Add(new XElement("users"));
var xml = xmlDoc.Root;

foreach (var user in users)
{
    xml.Add(new XElement("user", new XAttribute("first-name", user.FirstName?? ""), new XAttribute("last-name", user.LastName?? ""),
    new XElement("sold-products")));

    foreach (var product in user.Products)
    {
        .Add(new XElement("Product",
            new XElement("name", product.Name),
            new XElement("price", product.Price)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Checkout my documentation about XDocument this maybe can solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1528/xmldocument-and-the-system-xml-namespace#t=201704021228091722075

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
            XElement users = new XElement("users");
            xmlDoc.Add(users);

            foreach (var user in cUser.users)
            {
               XElement newUser =  new XElement("user", 
                   new XAttribute("first-name", user.FirstName?? ""), 
                   new XAttribute("last-name", user.LastName?? ""),
                   new XElement("sold-products")
               );
               users.Add(newUser);

               foreach (Product product in user.products)
               {
                  newUser.Add(new XElement("Product",
                     new XElement("name", product.Name),
                     new XElement("price", product.Price)
                  ));
               }
            }
        }
    }
    public class cUser
    {
        public static List<cUser> users { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<Product> products { get; set; }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this by keeping a reference to `sold-products`:

```
foreach (var user in users)
{
    var soldProducts = new XElement("sold-products");

    xml.Add(new XElement("user",
        new XAttribute("first-name", user.FirstName?? ""),
        new XAttribute("last-name", user.LastName?? ""),
        soldProducts));

    foreach (var product in user.Products)
    {
        soldProducts.Add(new XElement("Product",
            new XElement("name", product.Name),
            new XElement("price", product.Price)));
    }
}
```

Or by using a more declarative approach, which fits really nicely with LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("users",
        from user in users
        select new XElement("user",
            new XAttribute("first-name", user.FirstName ?? ""),
            new XAttribute("last-name", user.LastName ?? ""),
            new XElement("sold-products",
                from product in user.Products
                select new XElement("Product",
                    new XElement("name", product.Name),
                    new XElement("price", product.Price))))));
```

Comment: @M.Georgiev good stuff. Both should work, the second is just a different style; it describes the document rather than getting bogged down in the details of how it's created.

Comment: I have tried the second, but it throw me some exception

Comment: @M.Georgiev as you can see in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JBPz1C), this works fine. What sort of exception?